# Ocultar Edge en pruebas con Selenium En Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, edge

Por motivos que no vienen al caso, he tenido que utilizar Edge para mis pruebas automatizadas en selenium usando lenguaje Java.

Como puedo ocultar el navegador?

me sale un error en la segunda sentencia:  (ver foto)

`EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions(); options.addArguments("headless");`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: The method addArguments(String) is undefined for the type EdgeOptions